# ANdroid: Dynamicly add Image Buttons to rows in Table Layout

Tags: android, row, tablelayout

I need to add a number of rows to my Table layout and to each row I need to add two Image Buttons. Number of rows can be different each time I start the Activity - I look into a SQLite database and for each row in the database I need to add an Image Button. And there will be two Image Buttons in each row of Table layout. So far, I have this code:

```
db.open();
    int count = db.getCount();
    boolean newRow = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (newRow == true) {
            newRow = false;
            row = new TableRow(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
        ImageButton button = new ImageButton(this);
        row.addView(button);
        tableLayout.addView(row);
    }
    db.close();
```

TableRow row is defined above this block of code simply as variable for this Activity. My Table layout (tableLayout in code) is defined in XML code of the Activity layout:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayoutContacts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


</TableLayout>
```

The code crashes at the line

`tableLayout.addView(row);`

I wasnt able to resolve this. Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: How do you assign your TableLayout in Java code?

Comment: tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutContacts);

Comment: Well, there is like 30 errors (red lines) in my LogCat. It starts with a blue line "shutting down VM", than orange "threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)" and than follow the red lines starting with FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is different

It seems that Your code will have only one row and you are adding that row again and again to tableLayout as shown below.

```
tableLayout.addView(row);
```

This will lead to IllegalStateException at addViewInner Function of ViewGroup

try this

```
db.open();
    int count = db.getCount();
    boolean newRow = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            newRow = true;
        if (newRow == true) {
            newRow = false;
            row = new TableRow(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tableLayout.addView(row);
        }
        ImageButton button = new ImageButton(this);
        row.addView(button);

    }
    db.close();
```

Comment: Wow, I totaly didnt see that...but it works now, thanks very much! :) But there seems to be another little problem...I assumed that adding a new row will add it below the previous one. But I have all my buttons in a single row (at least opticaly) now...any hint? Thanks! :)

Comment: Try Edited Answer for Two Buttons in a row